# Events not working on cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, clone

I have a video slider that, in short, is not properly playing videos (and executing other functionality) when I clone slides within the slider. I have set the .clone() to true but this only helped with actually playing the videos but not other events inside of my play function.

My jQuery looks like:

```
var gallery = $('.slide-gallery');
            var rightButton = $('.video-slider .right a');
            var leftButton = $('.video-slider .left a');
            var slide = $('.slide-gallery .slide');
            var itemWidth = slide.outerWidth();
            var playButton = $('.play-button');
            var sliderVideo = $('.slider-video');
            var sliderOverlay = $('.video-slider .overlay-content');
            var rightIndent = parseInt(gallery.css('left'));
            var left = gallery.css("left");
            var item_width = slide.outerWidth(); 
            var left_indent = parseInt(gallery.css('left')) - item_width;
            var right_indent = parseInt(gallery.css('left'));
            var leftTwo = parseInt(left) * 2;

            // When clicking right arrow
            rightButton.click(function(){
                // call function below
                stopCurrentVideo();
                $('.slide-gallery .slide').eq(0).clone(true, true).appendTo(gallery);  
                gallery.animate({
                    'left' : left_indent
                },{
                    queue:false, 
                    duration:500, 
                    complete: function(){
                    $('.slide-gallery .slide').eq(0).remove(); 
                    gallery.css("left", left); 
                    } 
                });
            });

            // When clicking left arrow
            leftButton.click(function(){
                // call function below
                stopCurrentVideo();
                $('.slide-gallery .slide').eq(2).clone(true, true).prependTo(gallery); 
                gallery.css("left", leftTwo);
                gallery.animate({
                    'left' : right_indent
                },{
                    queue:false, 
                    duration:500, 
                    complete: function(){
                    $('.slide-gallery .slide').eq(3).remove(); 
                    gallery.css("left", left); 
                    } 
                });
            });

            function stopCurrentVideo(){
                // return playing video to loaded state, remove controls, and fade in overlay-content
                sliderVideo.load().removeAttr('controls');
                // bring the play button back
                playButton.fadeIn();
                // if window is greather than 1024 px;
                if ($(window).width() > 1024 ){
                    // bring back the overlay content
                    sliderVideo.siblings(sliderOverlay).fadeIn();
                }
            }

            // Video play functionality

            // when clicking play button
            playButton.on('click', function() {
                // hide play button
                $(this).hide();
                // hide overlay content
                sliderOverlay.fadeOut();
                // play the video
                $(this).parent().siblings(sliderVideo)[0].play();
            });

            sliderVideo.on('play', function() {
                // add controls to video that is playing
                $(this).attr('controls', '1');
            })
        }
```

As you can see, I am cloning the first or last slide and moving it to the front or back in order to make the slider a carousel.  I call a function within each slide transition to stop the current video and return the overlay elements to the slide.  All of the events within the playButton 'click' function started working when I set my clone to .clone(true, true).  However the events within the stopCurrentVideo function are still not working for the cloned slides.  Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: you can convert to delegated events instead of direct-bound ones, ex: using `.on()` instead of `.click()`

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I added .on() to both the left and right click functions but this does not solve my problem, the cloned elements are still ignoring the sotpCurrentVideo function.  Any idea why?